# Treat files on disk as option in command line

Tags: ruby, command-line

I want to make a command-line utility in ruby that when run, list the files in the current directory and shows it as an option list.

```
1 - somefile.txt
2 - somefile.pdf
3- somefile.whatever
```

So i can input let's say option 2 and **somefile.pdf** gets selected to do whatever i want to do.
Any directions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. In addition, please post **relevant** error messages *verbatim*, and take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob

Dir.glob will list all files in directory as array, all other steps are obvious.